# meteor.js - pushing array to user collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

**CONTEXT**

I've just created a new user and now want to push a value on to an array within my user collection. I'm using the following codes:

```
//User Schema - in User Collection
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
userEvents: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true
}, [...]


//User Methods - in server/methods
Meteor.methods({
  'addUserEvent': function (organizerId, params) {
   console.log(organizerId);
   console.log(params);     

    Meteor.users.update({ 
        organizerId: organizerId
    },{
        $set:params
      });
  }  
});

//Create new event and add ID of event to current user - in events controller
EventsController.events({
'click #mainEventType' : function(event) {

    var organizerId = Accounts.userId();
    var eventStatus = "processStarted";

    //get value from selection
    var mainEventType = event.target.alt;

    var eventParams = {
        organizerId: organizerId,
        mainEventType: mainEventType,
        eventStatus: eventStatus
    }


    //Insert Event and use callback to get the id of the even you just inserted
    Meteor.call('addEvent', eventParams, function(error, result){
        //use session set to store value of user id and event id
        Session.set("organizerId", Accounts.userId());          
        Session.set("myEventId", result)

        console.log("organizer ID: " + Session.get("organizerId"));
        console.log("usereventId: " + Session.get("myEventId"));



    });

    eventId = [] 
    eventId.push(Session.get("myEventId"))
    //set params for user   
    var userParams = {
        userEvents: eventId
    }

    console.log(userParams)

    Meteor.call('addUserEvent', Session.get("organizerId"), userParams);

}, [...]
```

**PROBLEM**

The two console logs in the User Method yield the correct values (i.e. of the event that was just created and of the current user). However, I am unable to add these to the user collection. Looking at it through both console and terminal (meteor mongo) reveals that the field hasn't been filled. Also, the `console.log`'s in the addUserEvent method are never being called, so maybe there is a problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling two methods client side. They are called asynchronously so the second call is already fired when the first is still executing. That's why you have callbacks. In order to fix your code, have the second call to `addUserEvent` inside the callback of `addEvent`.
And check `error` before calling `addUserEvent`.

Something like this:

```
//Insert Event and use callback to get the id of the even you just inserted
Meteor.call('addEvent', eventParams, function(error, result){
    //use session set to store value of user id and event id
    Session.set("organizerId", Accounts.userId());          
    Session.set("myEventId", result)

    console.log("organizer ID: " + Session.get("organizerId"));
    console.log("usereventId: " + Session.get("myEventId"));

    if (!error) {
        eventId = [] 
        eventId.push(Session.get("myEventId"))
       //set params for user   
       var userParams = {
           userEvents: eventId
       }

       console.log(userParams)

       Meteor.call('addUserEvent', Session.get("organizerId"), userParams);
    }

});
```

BTW, if you want access to `this`, add `.bind(this)` to the callback like this:

```
Meteor.call('addEvent', eventParams, function(error, result){
   // Your callback function body
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thank you - I just tried this approach and am still not not seeing the `console.log`'s from the User Method, nor the field added to my user collection. Any suggestions?

Comment: But the event 'click #mainEventType' is triggered? I would suggest extra log lines after `'click #mainEventType' : function(event) {` to see if anything goes wrong before it gets to the `Meteor.call('addEvent'`. And look in the browser's debugger to check undefined variables.

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the terminal and the User Method console.log are logging out after all. However, the field/value are still not being added to the collection. Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm trying to insert it into the main user collection rather than user.profile?

Comment: Ended up fixing this - thank you for your help and for letting me know about `bind(this)` - that was very useful in other parts of my work.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

For anyone else having a similar problem, the issue was that you need to use `$push` instead of `$set`. This is what the push function should look like:

```
'addUserEvent': function (organizerId, params) {

Meteor.users.update({
    _id: organizerId
    } , { 
    $push: params
 });

}
```